# Wordpress can't load js file from child

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes

I'm trying to load a JS file in my wordpress by enqueing it in the functions.php of my child theme.

```
function myChild_scripts() 
{
    if(is_page_template('page_alternative1.php')) 
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('accordion', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/js/accordion.js', array('jquery'), true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myChild');
```

But it doesn't appear in my source code.
I have check if it is added in the loop by using this function:

```
function print_filters_for( $hook = '' )
{
    global $wp_filter;
    if( empty( $hook ) || !isset( $wp_filter[$hook] ) )
    return;
    print '<pre>';
    print_r( $wp_filter[$hook] );
    print '</pre>';
}
```

And it seems to work:

```
 [myChild_scripts] => Array
 (
     [function] => myChild_scripts
     [accepted_args] => 1
 )
```

But I can't find the call in my header.
Any hints? I can't figure out what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

I apologyze, everything was OK but the template page name in the first conditional, that's why it wasn't loading...